# Virtual Environment won't create on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, virtualenv

I am just getting into Django and I'm trying to create a virtual environment, I am using windows 10. I have Pip and Python installed. However, when I try to create a virtual environment, I keep getting this in the cmd prompt over and over again. The message is: 
`Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\users\kenny james\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How are you trying to create the virtual environment? Also, I'm not sure this is something to be resolved, you should probably wait for the environment to be created.

Comment: in the tutorial I am following, this doesn't happen. also i am using `mkvirtualenv myenv` command

Comment: I think this would help you make a virtual environment in windows [here](https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/python-virtual-environment)